# MS Access - conditional concatentation

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access

I was given an Access db that contains a column of IDs that look like this:

```
374452-52
362619
483726
384810
384612-18
```

I want to concatenate a '-00' to the end of the the values that do not have a -dd. In other words, can I use a regular expression in MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this. Use `LIKE`:

```
select id & '-00'
from mytable
where id not like '%-%';
```

Or, to select all rows:

```
select iif(id like '%-%', id, id & '-00')
from mytable;
```

You can also use `INSTR` instead of `LIKE` if you prefer so.

Answer (score 0):

You would use update:

```
update t
    set id = id & "-00"
    where id not like "*-[0-9][0-9]"
```

You can test the logic using:

```
select iif(id not like "*-[0-9][0-9]", id & "-00", id) as new_id,
       t.*
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to concatenate '-00' only when the id does not end in: a dash, a digit, and a digit again. Regexp would be `/-[0-9][0-9]/` or `/-\d\d/` .

Here, I create the table, and then select from it:

```
CREATE TABLE input (
  id VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO input SELECT * FROM (
          SELECT '374452-52' FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '362619'    FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '483726'    FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '384810'    FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT '384612-18' FROM dual
) input;

SELECT
  IIF(
        LEFT(RIGHT(id,3),1)='-'
    AND LEFT(RIGHT(id,2),1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
    AND RIGHT(id,1)         BETWEEN '0' AND '9'
  , id
  , id & '-00'
  ) AS fixed_id
FROM input;

fixed_id
374452-52
362619-00
483726-00
384810-00
384612-18
374452-52
362619-00
483726-00
384810-00
384612-18
```